# Hide large title when scrolling up

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, xcode9-beta

I have a normal view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. In this view controller, I have a table view that is using the constraints of the safe area. (I don't use a table view controller)

The navigation controller is set to prefer large titles and the mode is set to .always. In beta 2 this worked perfectly, So when I came in the title was large and when I scrolled down it became small (Like the normal one). But since beta 3 this doesn't work anymore.

Anyone know how to turn this back on, or how to make it so when I scroll the table view it will become smaller. Like the behaviour of all the new iOS 11 apps?

Or is this a bug in the current version of swift 4/iOS 11 but the apps like messenger and settings still work this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For me, it was that if you set the boolean "Prefers Large Titles" in the storyboard to true it will stay large, if you turn this on by code it works as expected!

Comment: This is definitely a bug in iOS 11 but your tip worked for me as a workaround! Thank you!

Comment: Still the case in the GM build!

Comment: I filled a bug report and that one was set as duplicate so they should know about it.

Answer (score 12):

I found a workaround on this site
basically, if the tableView (or element that has scroll)is not the first view in your view hierarchy, the large title fails to hide automatically.

[image: Example that will NOT work]
[image: Example that will work]

https://markusbodner.com/2017/10/08/fix-large-navigation-bar-title-not-hiding-on-scroll-in-ios-11/

I added on the view willAppear:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: I did this on the Storyboard I attach the two images showing how hierarchy should be, edited ... I added code I used to set Large titles –

Comment: @SergioTrejo but how do you do to have the button under the table? In my case I have a view that must be under the a scrollView because is a background. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! that was it for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) { //20
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:NO];
    } else {   
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:YES];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "**Prefers Large Titles**" for your navigation bar in IB, or use:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Comment: Yes so I do this and the large title shows but never becomes small when I scroll down. It always stays big but when I scroll up and I’m at the top the title becomes even bigger. So the constraints also work properly, it’s just since beta 3 it doesn’t become small when I scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a programmatic layout and ran into a similar issue with large titles. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46692583/131378. In `viewDidLoad()` I had to toggle the `largeTitleDisplayMode` off and on again. That was the correct combination that got the large titles working with scrolling:

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```