# Back button animation with large title jumps

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

We have two `UIViewController` with an `UINavigationController`.

In the first presented VC inside of `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` we do:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        }
 ....
```

Inside of the second VC we deactive that behaviour with inside of `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    }
...
```

The transition animation to the second VC is smooth while tapping automatic generated back button causes the navigation controller title to create a strange `jump to large title` instead of the normal `grow to large title` animation as it does for example in the Messages App.

If i tap the tabbar icon as "back" operation, it does the right transition animation.

Any idea what could cause that issue or how i can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide large title when scrolling up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144324/hide-large-title-when-scrolling-up)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

on the second view controller set the `largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never`
you won't need to set the `prefersLargeTitles` to `false`.

To clarify things here, you've to set the `largeTitleDisplayMode` directly for the `navigationItem` of the view controller, not the navigation controller!

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never // This fixes the issue
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never // This doesn't work / Title will stay large
```

Comment: This will cause the nav bar to stay large but the back animation looks right. I want that the second VC does have a "small title", the first one a large one. It only decreases the title to a small one if i set `prefersLargeTitles` to false.

Comment: @BennX, this is a proper solution, I had the same problem and I have just tested it, thanks dave!

Comment: Add `self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never` in `viewDidLoad` instead of in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Seriously, this gets me *every time*. Apple are driving me insane with their insane layout defaults.

Answer (score 2):

@dave's answer worked for me! Thanks! Here's the code that I used in its entirety:

**FirstViewController:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

One should make force layout of navigation bar right after switching off large title

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This cancels out large navigation title immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same transition bug: from large title to small one or backwards. It was not growing/diminishing from one state to the another, but it was staying ugly on the screen for 1 sec, then just jumping from large to small or vice-versa.

The simple solution:

> Make sure each view controller has a navigationItem in the Storyboard.

[image: Navigation Item inside the view stack.]

> And for each navigationItem, set the corresponding `Large Title`
>   value:

[image: Navigation item attributes inspector]

Also, you don't need to set anything in `viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear`, etc. related to largeTitle. Just what I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was something completely different. In my project we set a custom back button without title on every VC. Standard way to do this for ages was to set an empty BarButtonItem like this:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
```

Removing that line fixed the jumping back button when moving from a VC with large title to one without large title. Still having design requirement I found out that since iOS 14 this can be done much more neatly:

```
navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
```

So just replace setting a new BarButtonItem with setting the display mode.