# Large navigation title bar is hidden by default

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Large navigations bars were displayed by default but it suddenly changed to smaller title, probably in a recent update. I'm experience this issue with `UICollectionViewController` even though to confirm, I add the following code to the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always;
```

Any leads appreciated! :)

Comment: I have also tried programmatically scrolling to the top, but this doesn't display the large navigation bar either. Interestingly, it shows when I tap on the status bar to scroll to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I referred to [iOS 11 large-title navigation bar not collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373055/ios-11-large-title-navigation-bar-not-collapsing) and although Apple has resolved the OPs issue, they introduced a new bug wherein if you set `prefersLargeTitle` and `c` via code, it results in large titles being displayed only when you manually scroll up.

**Fix**:

### - Check `largeTitleDisplayMode` via storyboard

### - Set `largeTitleDisplayMode` as "Automatic" via storyboard

### - Remove any similar code from your View Controllers

Comment: I couldn't find `largeTitleDisplayMode` option in the storyboard. I just checked `Prefers Large Titles` while inspecting the `Navigation Bar` of the root Navigation Controller in the storyboard and removed any germane code from the view controller's source file. That seemed to do the job.

Comment: Good point at explaining this Xcode bug, tried different configurations in code and none of them worked. @mohak you can find Storyboard's largeTitleDisplayMode on the Navigation Item of your NavigationController's root View Controller. Set the "Large Title" menu in the Attributes Inspector.