# prefersLargeTitles doesn't work with programmatic layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, swift4

I'm trying to add a table view programmatically, but large title doesn't show.

Here is my code:

```
self.view.addSubview(module.tableView)

module.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        module.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        module.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        module.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        module.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

Note: large titles enabled in view controller

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```

Maybe it's important: I'm trying to add a table as a child view controller. My child controller is a UITableViewController. And if I add child view in `viewDidLoad()` large title shows but doesn't scroll.

Here is the [link to file](https://github.com/ismetanin/Notty/blob/categories_adding/Notty/User%20Stories/Categories/Configurator/CategoriesModuleConfigurator.swift) where I'm adding my child module. Detail code you can see in question or [here](https://github.com/ismetanin/Notty/blob/categories_adding/Notty/User%20Stories/Categories/View/CategoriesViewController.swift) in `addChild(module:)` method.

Let me know how to fix this bug please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a programmatic layout and ran into a similar issue. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46692583/131378. In `viewDidLoad()` I had to toggle the `largeTitleDisplayMode` off and on again. That was the correct combination that got the large titles working with scrolling:

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable large titles in `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller where you're configuring the table view.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Comment: I've enabled this

Comment: Thanks. How is adding a table view connected with large titles? Does the large title work without the table related code?

Comment: Large title work without table(just showing large state). If I'm adding table view in storyboard all works perfect.
Maybe it's important: I'm trying to add a table as a child view controller

Comment: Can you post the code where you're adding it as a child?

Comment: Of course. Here is the [link to file](https://github.com/ismetanin/Notty/blob/categories_adding/Notty/User%20Stories/Categories/Configurator/CategoriesModuleConfigurator.swift) where I'm adding my child module. Detail code you can see in question or [here](https://github.com/ismetanin/Notty/blob/categories_adding/Notty/User%20Stories/Categories/View/CategoriesViewController.swift) in `addChild(module:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `iOS Deployment Target` to `11.0` or higher. Currently, it's at `10.3`. That's why you don't see the large titles.

Comment: I do see you have a navigation controller embedded within "Main.storyboard", but with your project setup you need to embed another one within "CategoriesViewController.storyboard".

Comment: CategoriesViewController is embedded programmatically in AppDelegate and there it is set as root view

Comment: Whoops! I overlooked that... I've edited my solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: New solution doesn't work
I see small title :(
Maybe it's important: if I add child view in `viewDidLoad()` large title shows but doesn't scroll

Comment: I checked out your project, and I realized the issue comes into play when `categoriesListModule` is added as a child to the `CategoriesViewController` instance inside of `CategoriesModuleConfigurator.swift`.

Comment: I've tried to add a table as a child view in `viewDidLoad()` but it didn't work

Comment: If you update your `Deployment Target`, and comment out adding `categoriesListModule` as a child to `CategoriesViewController`, you'll see the large title. It's not a solution to your current setup, but it will help you narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click your main Navigation Controller on Navigation Bar and then select "Prefers Large Titles" in your Attribute Inspector. [image]

Comment: I'm using `UINavigationController` programmatically and I tried to set `prefersLargeTitles` from code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the older answers doesn't work!
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/82213?answerId=662742022#662742022