# UITableViewController: how to not clip LargeTitle navigation bar when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, uitableview

I use UITableviewController inside of UINavigationController with PreferLargeTitle = true.
TableView use static cell and scrolling disable to it.
But when I tap on text view inside one of cell keyboard appears and TableView automatic scrolling up and clip NavigationBar. How can I turn off that automatic scrolling? Or how can I config NavigationBar always show LargeTitle?

Comment: "But when I tap on text view inside", If keyboard hides your textview, this will happen automatically in UITableViewController [Not in UIViewController].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373055/ios-11-large-title-navigation-bar-not-collapsing?rq=1

Comment: You can find something related to this.