# Swift Scroll View Not Working With Nav Bar

Tags: swift, scroll, scrollview, navbar

I have a view with a nav bar and `prefersLargeTitles = true`
I have added a ui scroll view with this code:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollView.contentSize.height = 800
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

This scroll view works but when u scroll down, it doesnt collapse the nav bar large title or when u go up, it doesnt pull down the large title as it should.

This is an idea of what I am aiming for where it pulls down on the large title and collapses when scroll down:

[image: Scroll View Example Of What I want help with]

Thanks

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649375/ios-11-large-navigation-bar-title-unexpected-velocity

Comment: It doesn't work but I see what they mean about table view controller bc I have one using a table view and it works how I want it. Any way to mimick how it works with table view for scroll view?

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383305/8447312

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work that way