# adding image behind UITableView make large title stop collapsing when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, preferslargetitles

I have a navigation large title and a table view, it all works fine, when I scroll the table view, the large title was still collapsing.

But after I add a image behind the table view, it's not collapsing anymore.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035243/6800631) that says it will not work if there's a subview under the SafeArea other than UITableView, but if that's the case, how can i add a background image behind the UITableView?

**Disclaimer:** I have this code because I want my image to move up when the large title collapse

```
backgroundImageTopConstraint.constant = backgroundImageTopConstraint.constant - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!
```

Comment: Every `UITableView` comes with a `backgroundView` where the default value is `nil`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614986-backgroundview. Can you try to add your image view as the `backgroundView` of the the table view you have?

Comment: @SauvikDolui but I need to constraint it to the safe area