How do I implement the navigation title of the iPhone's default music app?
I would like to implement it so that, like the iPhone's default music app, it is shown as a large title at first and when you scroll up, it is shown as a small title. So I implemented it as below, but it is not smooth and hard like the music app. I tried animation, but it is not the same.
How should I implement it?
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        }
    }
}


The title collapsing when you scroll is the default behaviour. You shouldn't need to write any extra code to achieve this. Can you show a [mcve] that shows that this is not the case?

@Sweeper - I had no idea it was a basic feature. Thank you so much. After seeing your comment, I found the article below and solved the problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373055/ios-11-large-title-navigation-bar-not-collapsing
